# V-USB send special command

Tags: arduino

I've created a keyboard-like with v-usb. I wonder if it's possible to send special command like on my Logitech keyboard to open Calc, increase/decrease volume, shutdown PC, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It ought to be achievable. First you *may* need to pretend to be a Logitech keyboard, in the event that certain scan codes are only acted on if the keyboard type matches.

Second, you would need to find out what the scan code is for those keys. You might get help at [Scan Codes Demystified](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm) and [USB IDs](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids).